# How do I compile and install gnome-tweak-tool from its git repository?

Tags: installation, compiling, git, gnome-tweak-tool

How I install the Gnome tweak tool from git://git.gnome.org/gnome-tweak-tool?
I have install the Synaptic

Comment: Why do you want to install gnome-tweak-tool from git? Most people will just want to install the **gnome-tweak-tool** package.

Comment: I want the new one for the official site

Answer (score 2):

In the readme you'll see these instructions:

> Running
>   -------  * If you wish to run the application uninstalled, execute;
>
> ./gnome-tweak-tool [-p /path/to/jhbuild/prefix/]
>
> - If you wish to install system wide you must
>
> ./autogen.sh && make && make install

You'll probably need "build-essentials" and "automake" to compile the program, but I'm not sure what gnome-tweak-tool's specific requirements are.  Try install those two packages, and then within the folder you downloaded with git (`git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-tweak-tool`) run the commands it listed in the readme to install. If it gives you any errors, come back and ask us about those?